# IIS Rewrite using IIS Manager

Tags: iis, rewrite, asp.net-mvc

Hi there I am attempted to do a proper IIS rewrite utilizing the IIS manager credentials my hosting provider has given me. I have no experience with this and the articles I have read online so far have not been too helpful.

Here is the scenario: I have an ASP.net MVC 5 website (**`reallylongmaindomain.com`**, for ease of reading) that physically has the files uploaded to it. It is secured with an SSL certificate. The literature we are handing out has a shorter domain (not a URL-shortened domain) that we will call **`shortdomain.com`**, which **does not** have any files. However, if you navigate to **`shortdomain.com`**, you get an SSL domain name mismatch error (ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID to be precise). This is what I need to avoid.

In comes the IIS manager. I have successfully logged in to the system and added a URL Rewrite. This is the rule I have: **`(http(s)?://)?(www.)?shortdomain.com`**. This handles any **`http/https`** and/or **`www`** that the user may put in the address bar. The action properties are set to "Redirect" (Permanent 301) and the Redirect URL is set to **`https://reallylongmaindomain.com`**, but I am still getting the SSL certificate error and the URL in the window is still **`shortdomain.com`**.

I am sure I am just missing a simple thing or two. <del>Do I also need to add the rule into my Web.Config file? I was under the impression the IIS manager rules superseded the Web.Config rules.</del> **EDIT**: The rule was added to my web.config, here it is:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="site redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(http(s)?://)?(www.)?shortdomain.com" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://reallylongmaindomain.com" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is the rule I was looking for:

```
<rewrite>
    <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)?shortdomain.com" />                 
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://reallylongmaindomain.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rewrite>
```

After applying this rule, navigating to **`shortdomain.com`** resolves perfectly fine to **`https://reallylongmaindomain.com`**.

Hopefully this helps someone else out!